# How do I catch JSON parse errors with JQuery JSON calls?

Tags: javascript, json, jquery

I'm making AJAX calls to a server that sometimes return unparseable JSON. The server isn't under my control, so I can't fix that.

```
function eventFunction(evt) {
    $('div#status_bar').show();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://buggyserver.com/api/',
        type: 'GET',
        data: { 'mode': 'json', 'q': 'get/data' },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: updateForm
    });
}

function updateForm(returned, status) {
    if (status == 'success') {
        //Update the form here
    }
    $('div#status_bar').hide();
}
```

When unparseable JSON is returned, the `updateForm` functions does not get called.

How can I, on the client side, ensure that the last line of the `updateForm` function gets called to hide the status bar when? I've tried putting `try { } catch {}` clauses around both the AJAX call and the updateForm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
function eventFunction(evt) {
    $('div#status_bar').show();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://buggyserver.com/api/',
        type: 'GET',
        data: { 'mode': 'json', 'q': 'get/data' },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: updateForm,
        complete: function() { $('div#status_bar').hide(); }
    });
}

function updateForm(returned) {
   //Update the form here
}
```

The `complete` callback fires after success, whether it was successful or not.